How to intercept traffic moving through Windows sharing?
A Windows 11 PC, with both wired and Wi-Fi NICs, is set up with sharing enabled so the PC can act as a hotspot. The wired NIC is connected with the gateway router.
Wireshark shows traffic coming into the PC’s wired adapter destined for 130.211.9.161:443. That traffic is from a wireless connected device arriving into the Wi-Fi being sent by Windows sharing through to the wired NIC. The wireless traffic could be from any wireless device connected, weather station, IP camera, smartTV, etc…, connected to the PC's Wi-Fi hotspot.
The goal is to have a program listening on a socket for port 443, on the sharing enabled PC, intercept the traffic, basically so the device believes it is communicating with 130.211.9.161:443.
How to implement a mechanism to intercept traffic in that manner?

Are you trying to figure out what the device at 130... is, or are you trying to pretend to be that device for troubleshooting or development purposes, or something else? Understanding the reason behind this request may help us find the better solution for you.

If what your are looking is what is behind 130.211.9.161, it is a Google IP address located at Kansas city. Look at this: https://ipinfo.io/130.211.9.161 If you are looking something else, please edit your post with more details.

In this case the purpose for the program listening on the socket is to pretend to be the server at 130.211.9.161:443 in order to intercept and decode the readings the weather station is sending to the server at 130.211.9.161:443.
Of course, the TCP traffic is destined for 130.211.9.161:443 rather than the PC. It seems like it somehow needs to be redirected to the PC so it can be picked up on the socket.
TY!

This will probably involve rules on your firewall or proxying device on your network, if it can handle that, routing the traffic intended for the public server to this internal device. On your own network you have full control, but if the traffic is outside your network, you have no control. Can you share the research you have done and things you've tried so far? Also, some information about your network, and in particular.

@music2myear, All this would take place on the internal LAN. The device, weather station in this case, has a Wi-Fi connection to the Windows 11 PC with sharing enabled (so the PC functions as a Wi-Fi hotspot). The weather station, as seen via Wireshark on the PC, is sending TCP traffic to 130.211.9.161:443 (an external IP address). My goal is for a program on the PC listening on a socket for port 443 to catch the traffic before it is sent to the gateway router. Of course, nothing comes to that socket because Windows routes the traffic to the wired NIC for the gateway. Does this help? TY!

This has been solved, which of course now that it is solved, the solution is obvious...
Looking closer at the Wireshark trace, the device initiates a DNS query just before starting the TCP session. Easy enough to add an entry to the PC's "hosts" file to provide the PC's IP address in response to the DNS query.
Now a program on the PC listening on a socket:port 443 gets the connection. That program provides a dynamically constructed, self-signed SSL certificate, which the device accepts. Now the device carries on as though it is communicating with its intended server.
As in most LANs the PCs on the LAN get their IP addresses from DHCP -> so a scheme needs to be created that keeps the "hosts" file current with DHCP.
